# What is Database Connection Alias in DbExecute present in General System Palette in Process Designer?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-process-engine

What is Database Connection Alias in DbExecute present in General System Palette in Process Designer?

These are the details of tools I am using:

- Process Designer 5.2.1
- OS: Windows
- Filenet Platform: 5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

DbExecute system function is used to run a stored procedure in a specified database. So you specify the DB connection name in **DB Connection Alias** of the process designer. Before this, you need to define DB connection with parameters. You do that using ACCE.

Refer to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8toc.doc/welcome_p8.htm) documentation for more help.